# user_delete_multiple throws InvalidPluginDefinitionException

Tags: 8, users

I'm working on a small custom module that runs on a Drupal 8.5.1 site, and that automatically deletes user accounts that have been deactivated over 30 days ago. I'm using `hook_cron()`.

It doesn't work, though: None of the user accounts is deleted, and in the log I find the following error message.

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidPluginDefinitionException: The "user" entity type did not specify a "delete" form class. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getFormObject() (regel 184 van /home/xxx_staging/apps/default/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php).

This is the `hook_cron()` implementation I am using.

```
function xxx_delete_inactive_users_cron(){  
  $time_for_clearing = _xxx_delete_inactive_users_time_for_clearing();

  if($time_for_clearing->is_due === TRUE){
    // first switch to admin account
    $accountSwitcher = Drupal::service('account_switcher'); 
    $account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $accountSwitcher->switchTo($account); 

    // get users that have been deactivated over 30 days ago
    $user_ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
      ->condition('status', 0)
      ->condition('changed', $time_for_clearing->from_timestamp, '>')
      ->condition('changed', $time_for_clearing->to_timestamp, '<=')
      ->execute();

    // flatten array
    $user_id_values = array_values($user_ids);
    // delete the whole bunch
    user_delete_multiple($user_id_values);
    // log
    \Drupal::logger('xxx_delete_inactive_users')->notice('deleted user ids:     ' . implode(', ', $user_id_values));
    // switch back
    $accountSwitcher->switchBack();
  }
}
```

What's going on? I know `user_delete_multiple()` is deprecated, but it still should work.

**EDIT**: To make things significantly more interesting: if I run the above user delete code in Devel php screen on the same installation, it works fine. 
I suppose it must be something about the cron context that causes it to fail.

The only contrib module I've found that is active that implements hook_entity_delete is webform. I do not think webform is to blame.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! `user_delete_multiple()` should not throw that exception, since it doesn't show any confirmation form for deleting the user accounts. I would guess there is a third-party module doing something wrong. Yes, it is true the *User* entity doesn't define a *delete* form; it has a *cancel* form. Drupal core would not try creating a *delete* form for the *User* entity.

Comment: @kiamlaluno : what hook(s) would you imagine I should be looking for in my modules? Where could a module hook itself into this call?

Comment: Modules can implement [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_delete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_delete/8.6.x) or the more generic [`hook_entity_delete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_delete/8.6.x). Keep in mind that, in the first case, for the _User_ entity, and the example module, the hook implementation is `example_user_delete()`.

Comment: I'd be looking for `'delete'` or `"delete"` in contrib modules.

Comment: @kiamlaluno : The plot thickens. My code works if I run it directly, but not in the cron hook. See my edit.